# Prevent replacing an already replaced string in comma-separated string

Tags: c#, string

I have a string which is

```
string mainstr = "NONSALE_REVENUE,SALE_REVENUE";
```

I am trying to replace `NONSALE_REVENUE` with `SUM(NONSALE_REVENUE)` and `SALE_REVENUE` with `SUM(SALE_REVENUE)`

What I have tried is :

```
 mainstr = mainstr.Replace("SALE_REVENUE", "SUM(SALE_REVENUE)");
 mainstr = mainstr.Replace("NONSALE_REVENUE", "SUM(NONSALE_REVENUE)");
```

Which is giving me wrong result:

`NONSUM(SALE_REVENUE,SUM(SALE_REVENUE`

My Expected result is `SUM(NONSALE_REVENUE),SUM(SALE_REVENUE)`

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: It brings lot of questions: is it every time 2 strings separated by comma? Can it be more? Will you change every item in string to Sum(string)? Maybe you will decide to change only first? Or it's just this string and you want to replace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with RegEx

```
string mainstr = "NONSALE_REVENUE,SALE_REVENUE";
string newString = Regex.Replace(mainstr, @"\bNONSALE_REVENUE\b", "SUM(NONSALE_REVENUE)");
newString = Regex.Replace(newString, @"\bSALE_REVENUE\b", "SUM(SALE_REVENUE)");

Console.WriteLine(newString);
```

Comment: With regex, you do not have to use 2 operations. Just use one correct regex then. Also, why not leverage backreferences in the replacement pattern?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, how could we achieve this in single regex operation? I am not guru in RegEx. It would be great if you give some insights on it

Comment: I  personally liked elegant solution suggested by @fubo, not sure why OP accepted my  answer

Comment: Maybe @Pinku needs to only wrap certain substring with `SUM()`, not all. Besides, this answer - although not that efficient - is extremely readable. I updated my answer to actually replace strings between commas with `Regex.Replace(mainstr, @"(?<![^,])(?:NON)?SALE_REVENUE(?![^,])", "SUM($&)")` though, it seems more correct than word boundaries.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the `,` char to detect the single values

```
string mainstr = "NONSALE_REVENUE,SALE_REVENUE";
string result = string.Join(",", mainstr.Split(',').Select(x => "SUM("+ x + ")"));
```

Answer (score 3):

A single regex replacement step:

```
Regex.Replace(mainstr, @"(?:NON)?SALE_REVENUE", "SUM($&)")
```

If you want to ensure you replace a whole word, enclose the pattern with `\b` (word boundaries):

```
Regex.Replace(mainstr, @"\b(?:NON)?SALE_REVENUE\b", "SUM($&)")
```

Or, **if it is important to only match a substring between commas and/or at the start/end of string**, use

```
Regex.Replace(mainstr, @"(?<![^,])(?:NON)?SALE_REVENUE(?![^,])", "SUM($&)")
```

where `(?<![^,])` is a negative lookbehind that requires no non-comma char immediately to the left and the `(?![^,])` is a negative lookahead that requires no non-comma char immediately to the right of the search phrase.

The `$&` in the replacement pattern inserts the whole match during the replacement.

See the [regex demo online](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5b%5e%2c%5d%29%28%3f%3aNON%29%3fSALE_REVENUE%28%3f!%5b%5e%2c%5d%29&i=NONSALE_REVENUE%2cSALE_REVENUE&r=SUM%28%24%26%29).

**Pattern details**

- `\b` - a word boundary or
- `(?<![^,])` - a negative lookbehind that requires no non-comma char immediately to the left
- `(?:NON)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of `NON`
- `SALE_REVENUE` - a literal substring
- `(?![^,])` - a negative lookahead that requires no non-comma char immediately to the right of the search phrase or
- `\b` - (closing) word boundary.

[image]

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/po1qDI):

```
string mainstr = "NONSALE_REVENUE,SALE_REVENUE";
string result = Regex.Replace(mainstr, @"(?<![^,])(?:NON)?SALE_REVENUE(?![^,])", "SUM($&)");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

If `mainstr` is **always** going to be `"NONSALE_REVENUE,SALE_REVENUE"`, then use the comma as part of your replace operation, so use this:

```
mainstr = mainstr.Replace(",SALE_REVENUE", ",SUM(SALE_REVENUE)");
mainstr = mainstr.Replace("NONSALE_REVENUE,", "SUM(NONSALE_REVENUE),");
```

Comment: I loved fubo's answer a lot, but this one just takes the cake for being so... dirty. I've got to go wash myself now.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't had much sleep, fubo's answer is probably the sensible option

Answer (score 1):

Using `Regex.Replace`:

```
string mainstr = "NONSALE_REVENUE,SALE_REVENUE";
string result = Regex.Replace(mainstr, @"\b\w+\b", "SUM($0)");
```